# Why is radix sort O(nd) but merge sort isn't O(d*nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort, radix-sort

Often when people talk about the complexity of sorting algorithms, I see this explanation:

> The complexity of Radix Sort is `O(nd)`, where `n` is the length of the
>   list and `d` is the number of digits

and

> The complexity of Merge Sort is `O(n log n)`, where `n` is the length of the
>   list

This is almost as-if to justify that radix sort is somehow often slower than Merge Sort, even though it doesn’t make any sense.

There are two cases:

**Case 1:** We’re sorting normal integers, which have four bytes. 
Here, comparisons take constant time, so `O(n log n)` makes sense to describe merge sort. But, when sorting normal integers, `d` in `O(nd)` is a constant (perhaps 4, for base 16 — or 16, for base 2. Either way, it’s a constant, and the number of bins in bin sort called by radix sort scales to compensate for that). So, wouldn’t it make more sense to say that radix sort is `O(n)` and merge sort has an objectively worse complexity, at `O(nlogn)`?

**Case 2:** We’re sorting strings, which could be thought of as numbers with any number of digits in base ASCII.
Here, comparisons take `O(d)` time, because the worse case is comparing `AAAAAAAAB` to `AAAAAAAAC`, which could take a long time.
In this case, it totally makes sense to say radix sort has complexity `O(nd)`, because `d` varies with respect to the input.
However, wouldn’t it also follow that merge sort in this scenario should be considered `O(d*nlogn)`, because comparison time is no longer constant?

It seems to me that people don’t believe radix sort is fast enough to use, and they justify it’s large time constant by making it look worse than comparison based sorts by equivocating their complexity descriptions.

I appologize for the poor formatting, I'm not sure how to make it look any better on stackoverflow yet

Comment: formatting is simply a matter of using the buttons above the text box....Aside from that, what's the actual question? Radix sort requires fixed size keys; you use it when you have fixed size keys...

Comment: The question is in the box that normally holds code, but I'm using it to keep my whitespace in tact

Comment: Also, it's trivial to adapt radix sort to sort integer strings of variable length - it still takes O(n) time. One method is to sort them by length first, and as long as their length is less than 2^32, you can use radix sort for that too.

Comment: @MitchWheat Radex sort can be used on strings too, see [here](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/opetus/13s/spa/lecture03.pdf)

Comment: If you have a probabilistic model for your strings, then the average cost of a string comparison in merge sort usually works out to O(1), or at least < O(log N).  In cases where that's not realistic, radix sort can be a lot faster

Answer (score 2):

Mergesort when comparing character-by-character (or digit-by-digit) would be `O(d n log n)` operations. But you can sort any type of object and a comparison can be any function on those objects, thus such a representation would be too specific - you'd need some other complexity to represent the same mergesort algorithm using a different method of comparison.

It makes more sense to represent the complexity in terms of number of **comparisons**, so you can say mergesort is always `O(n log n)` comparisons.

A comparison is also typically assumed to be a really fast operation, i.e. constant time (even if this isn't true as a general rule). Radix sort, on the other hand, requires looping over the input for each digit - you can't really say it doesn't matter how many loops there are.

Comparing the complexity of mergesort and radix sort is comparing apples and oranges to some extent.